# iOS format mathematical function nicely

Tags: ios, math, ios9

What is the best way to format a mathematical expression/function such as `x²` nicely in iOS. I thought about using mathml and `WKWebView` but this doesn't seem very efficient. Is there any API or simple way to achieve the formatting? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is neatly format exponents, you could use `NSAttributedString`. It would something like this:

```
NSString *exponentString = @"X2";

NSMutableAttributedString *formattedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:exponentString];

[formattedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@1 range:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
```

Comment: I want to be able to format roots etc. too so this wouldn't be acceptable